# Scroll one vertically centered DIV without scrolling the other in the same box

Tags: scroll, css-position, vertical-alignment

Been working on this all night, had no idea it would be so hard. My goal is explained in words within this fiddle, if you just wanna skip to that: http://jsfiddle.net/6VZeD/

Basically, I want a floated, fixed-size testimonial box to contain two elements, `a.part` and `.full`, both of which are vertically centered, even with multiple lines. When `.full` overflows, causing a scrollbar, I want to scroll `.full` while `a.part` remains vertically centered. I can't absolutely position `a.part` because it needs to center vertically at any size. So I wrapped `a.part` in an absolutely positioned element, but that scrolls along with `.full`. No bueno.

I left some elements out of the fiddle for simplicity, but in case it matters, I'm using jQuery isotope to position the fixed-size boxes, and I'm expanding the boxes (width, height, top-margin, and left-margin change) on hover. So I'm happy to add divs within `.testimonial`, but I can't wrap anything around `.testimonial` (though I can add classes to it). I started exploring jQuery solutions involving .hide() and .offset() but things started to get messy, especially because I'm using CSS transitions heavily. So I'm hoping to avoid Javascript if possible.

Here's the fiddle HTML:

```
<div class="box praise testimonial">
    <div class="abs1">
        <a class="part" href="#">stay vertically centered!<br/>even if you scroll!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="abs2">
        <div class="full">
            <p>This text is larger than its containing box, and I want a scrollbar to appear. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum vitae nisl at justo sodales congue. Praesent sed arcu sit amet dolor molestie venenatis. Curabitur et consequat libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed posuere lectus nec est viverra faucibus scelerisque massa fermentum. Donec ultricies bibendum tincidunt. Sed sit amet mi massa, a egestas arcu. Maecenas vitae libero metus. Proin dolor lorem, molestie ut ullamcorper sit amet, varius sit amet urna. Nunc aliquet scelerisque dui, et tristique quam molestie vitae. Etiam ac justo sapien. Etiam ipsum ante, porttitor posuere placerat id, congue quis neque. Nunc et elementum odio. Sed vulputate semper erat, a lobortis dolor porttitor ut.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box praise testimonial">
    <div class="abs1">
        <a class="part" href="#">stay vertically centered!<br/>even if you scroll!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="abs2">
        <div class="full">
            <p>this<br/>should<br/>stay<br/>centered<br/>too!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
}
a { color: #fff; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
    background: #777;
}
.testimonial, .testimonial .abs1, .testimonial .abs2, .testimonial a.part, .testimonial .full {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
.testimonial:hover {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
.testimonial a.part {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
}
.testimonial .abs1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.testimonial .abs2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.testimonial .full {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

Any help would earn my undying appreciation.

Comment: Sounds not yet clear (to me). You want 1. Isotope .items in your #container that 2. contain overflowing .full content (texts and maybe images) that cause scrollbars and 3. on top of that scrollable content, you want some bold white vertically and horizontally centered .part text that does **not** scroll with the content underneath? So, .full and .part must both be inside the Isotope .item, but .part must not be contained inside .full, otherwise it would scroll.

Comment: .part is not contained within .full, yet it scrolls with .full. That is the problem.

Comment: Well, I solved that part for you in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [the solution in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZzAK/) which also centers mulitple lines of text over images.

Comment: Thank you. But notice the third box: "This text is shorter than its containing box, and it should be centered vertically." in this update: http://jsfiddle.net/FZzAK/1/

Comment: Yes, maybe the height of the horizontal scrollbar which is introduced plays a role ;)

Comment: I don't think what I'm asking for is possible in CSS. But thanks so much for your help! I'm just gonna ditch the scrollbars in my design.

Comment: Well, it does work according to your initial question, no? All you need now is a class that takes the scrollbar's height into consideration on elements that have **no** overflowing content in them. You can either hard code this, or do it via a bit of jQuery dynamically; but that would be another topic...

Comment: Nope, cuz .artwork and .caption both need to be vertically centered. If I add `display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;` to .artwork, it centers but overflows the box if it's too big. But really don't spend time on it unless you want to; I ditched the scrollbar idea in my design so the problem need not be solved.